# Ubuntu 12.04 server - How to interpret this syslog entries about eth0 interface?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I am getting in my Ubuntu 12.04 server the following errors in syslog/dmesg.
Recently the server became multiple times slow in network and causing at time hung application and many errors with postgresql-9.1 server running on it.

Log snippet from dmesg

```
[    5.923148] tg3 0000:03:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.923155] tg3 0000:03:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.923160] tg3 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.923165] tg3 0000:03:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.923169] tg3 0000:03:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.045713] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.716179] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[    7.716184] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[    7.716185] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: EEE is disabled
[    7.716268] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Log snippet (more occurrences) from syslog.

```
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    1.848502] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5720000] (PCI Express) MAC address 40:a8:f0:c7:32:a8
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    1.848506] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5720C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    1.848508] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    1.848510] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    3.684380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 18:25:08 sugam kernel: [    5.524600] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 18:25:10 sugam kernel: [    7.174179] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
Jul 31 18:25:10 sugam kernel: [    7.174183] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Jul 31 18:25:10 sugam kernel: [    7.174184] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: EEE is disabled
Jul 31 18:25:10 sugam kernel: [    7.174269] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    1.902218] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5720000] (PCI Express) MAC address 40:a8:f0:c7:32:a8
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    1.902222] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5720C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    1.902224] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    1.902226] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    3.730192] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 18:58:24 sugam kernel: [    5.644533] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 18:58:26 sugam kernel: [    7.234780] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
Jul 31 18:58:26 sugam kernel: [    7.234784] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Jul 31 18:58:26 sugam kernel: [    7.234785] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: EEE is disabled
Jul 31 18:58:26 sugam kernel: [    7.234865] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    1.833042] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(N/A) rev 5720000] (PCI Express) MAC address 40:a8:f0:c7:32:a8
Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    1.833046] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5720C (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    1.833048] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    1.833050] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    3.457417] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 19:07:19 sugam kernel: [    6.045713] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 31 19:07:20 sugam kernel: [    7.716179] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
Jul 31 19:07:20 sugam kernel: [    7.716184] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
Jul 31 19:07:20 sugam kernel: [    7.716185] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth0: EEE is disabled
Jul 31 19:07:20 sugam kernel: [    7.716268] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Any help is appreciated as I need to figure out what is going on with this server.

Comment: None of those seem to be errors; merely information. Also, by the timestamp, the messages appear during the boot process and not randomly during operation. After the speeds are reduced, I'd look at: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth0` Perhaps there is a better clue there.

Comment: The second snipper is cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth0

Comment: I still see nothing that's an error. The hardware comes on, is recognized, negotiates 100 Mbps and full duplex, flow control is turned off, Energy Efficient Ethernet (EEE) is disabled and it connects. I still see nothing wrong; read, fixable.

Comment: I suspect some network delay and errors. So was wondering why "Jul 31 19:07:18 sugam kernel: [    3.457417] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready" twice before it comes Ready

Comment: The case may be that all looks good. I wanted to confirm if as I got random slow application performance from this system and needed to rule out possibility of any network problems if any, indicated by these log entries.